# Adding custom registration field and check its value

Tags: php, wordpress, field, registration, extra

We need to customize the WordPress registration form by adding a "Code" field that stores some value at backend like

Code = some value/text/number

Then at front-end when the user wants to register into the website they enter their information like Email address, password with the passcode which we set at back-end.

Then our code checks the user has entered the valid code or not.. if yes, then immediately registered into the website. And if not, system says invalid code entered.

Please help with this functionality

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: We have customized this example according to our requirements: https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-the-wordpress-registration-form/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by applying some conditions on the code.